# Who paid the bill for cheap Chinese exports?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics, china

We have all enjoyed the flow of cheap Chinese imported goods, whether in the shops, or online.

The shipping costs from China have always seemed very low.

Now I see [this note](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/its-official-no-more-cheap-shipping-for-chinese-sellers/493043):

> Got notification today that all USPS international GEPS contracts will be terminated September 31st.
>
> This is all related to the Universal Postal Union agreement that allows Chinese sellers to ship products to the U.S. for less than it costs us to ship to the same state.
>
> The administration has given the UPU an ultimatum, that they: either allow the USPS to set rates for China mail that arrives in the U.S., or the U.S. will officially leave the UPU on October 17th.
>
> Either way, this means as of October 17, no more cheap Chinese shipping. They will have to pay the same domestic rates as us once their e-packets arrive here.
>
> This is great news for U.S. sellers, especially eBay sellers.

My question is: **Who paid the bill for cheap Chinese export shipping?**

Comment: I assume, USA national security department ;-)

Comment: September 31st? Is this normal in contract lingo?

Comment: @Giskard - are you concerned about September only having 30 days?

Comment: @Henry Indeed I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The United States [was paying the bill](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-un-postal/u-n-postal-union-clinches-deal-to-keep-u-s-in-club-idUSKBN1WA247). (This has now changed).